# esp32 http client response only 200 didn't receive the data after that

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, esp32, http, iot

i am using esp32 as a client and using following example. So here i am getting header response only that is 200. I am not getting any response after that. here is the example

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
 
const char* ssid = "yourNetworkName";
const char* password =  "yourPassword";
 
void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(4000);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
 
}
 
void loop() {
 
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { //Check the current connection status
 
    HTTPClient http;
 
    http.begin("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?id=10"); //Specify the URL
    int httpCode = http.GET();                                        //Make the request
 
    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code
 
        String payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println(httpCode);
        Serial.println(payload);
      }
 
    else {
      Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }
 
    http.end(); //Free the resources
  }
 
  delay(10000);
 
}
```

given url works with me as well. but if i give other url then i am getting response as 200 only. but not receiving json data which is present on the request url.

Comment: Your code works without any problem. What do you means "but if i give other url"? BTW, if you are using esp32, don't tag esp8266.

Answer (score 2):

A 200 response doesn't guarantee that your `payload` will actually contain any data. It depends on the server. The server might determine to respond with a 200 code but still not return any JSON code for your request.

I am not at all sure, but the server may be rejecting your request because it doesn't like your user agent. I have seen my own ESP8266 supply ESP8266HTTPClient as its user agent for HTTP requests. You can see from the [source code](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/52f4cc8de06671a44a27886f4df84777731cb4a6/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp) of the HttpClient class that this is the default:

```
HTTPClient::HTTPClient()
    : _client(nullptr), _userAgent(F("ESP8266HTTPClient"))
{
// etc...
}
```

You might consider setting the user agent for your http client object:

```
http.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0");
```

If you'd like to investigate a bit more, you might use curl from the command line (this works on linux) to emulate the http request being formulated by your ESP device:

```
curl -vA "ESP8266HTTPClient" http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?id=10
```

On my linux machine, this returns all the HTTP header information, followed by some JSON for the url you've specified in your code:

```
[
  {
    "postId": 2,
    "id": 10,
    "name": "eaque et deleniti atque tenetur ut quo ut",
    "email": "REDACTED@EXAMPLE.COM",
    "body": "voluptate iusto quis nobis reprehenderit ipsum amet nulla\nquia quas dolores velit et non\naut quia necessitatibus\nnostrum quaerat nulla et accusamus nisi facilis"
  }
]
```

Maybe try that with the other url and see what comes out?

You might also modify your post with the Serial output of your sketch to provide more detail.