# ESP32-S3 - HttpClient only returns 200 status code no JSON payload data

Tags: esp32, wifi, http

I have a ESP-S3 board and am trying to get JSON data from our server. I am using the following code (see below) as a basis for mine.

This code works. If I change

```
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?id=10
```

to
http://mywebsite.com

I do get the html for our server's main page.

If I then change

```
http://mywebsite.com
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.com/profiles
```

I get status code 200 but no JSON.

I type http://mywebsite.com/profiles in a browser it returns the JSON or if I use postman and do a GET on http://mywebsite.com/profiles it returns JSON.

It sounds like this issue posted a couple of years ago:
[esp32 http client response only 200 didn't receive the data after that](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/76788/esp32-http-client-response-only-200-didnt-receive-the-data-after-that)

Any insight as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
 
const char* ssid = "yourNetworkName";
const char* password =  "yourPassword";
 
void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(4000);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
 
}
 
void loop() {
 
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { //Check the current connection status
 
    HTTPClient http;
 
    http.begin("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?id=10"); //Specify the URL
    int httpCode = http.GET();                                        //Make the request
 
    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code
 
        String payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println(httpCode);
        Serial.println(payload);
      }
 
    else {
      Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }
 
    http.end(); //Free the resources
  }
 
  delay(10000);
 
}
```

Comment: how big is the JSON response? There's not a huge amount of room for large responses. Try a smaller response and see if you still get nothing.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you experienced, your code works perfectly and I got the json back. The only difference is that I'm using an ESP32 instead of ESP32S3. Maybe you try to swap the lines between `String payload = http.getString();` and `Serial.println(httpCode);`, this might provided sufficient time for payload to be received completely.

Comment: dandavis - that is definitely something to check. thank you for the suggestion. hcheung - the above code works for me too. It fails when I use my server.

Comment: dandavis - that was the issue. a smaller response size worked.